Perform MongoUpdate using springboot
I have a service file created with the below content
package com.pichain.apimeter.service;


import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Criteria;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.query.Update;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.pichain.apimeter.model.OrgWallet;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public interface OrgWalletRepoCustom {
    void updateAmountByOrgId(String orgId, Double cost);
}

@Service
class OrgWalletRepoImpl implements OrgWalletRepoCustom {

    private final MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    public OrgWalletRepoImpl(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        this.mongoTemplate = mongoTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public void updateAmountByOrgId(String orgId, Double cost) {
        Query query = new Query(Criteria.where("orgId").is(orgId));
        Update update = new Update().inc("amount", cost);
        mongoTemplate.updateFirst(query, update, OrgWallet.class);
        System.out.println("MONGO UPDATED");
    }
}


And, there's a repo file with the content as follows
package com.pichain.apimeter.repositories;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.Update;

import java.util.List;
import com.pichain.apimeter.model.OrgWallet;

public interface OrgWalletRepo extends MongoRepository<OrgWallet, String> {

    void updateAmountByOrgId(String orgId, Double cost);
}

When I use the updateAmountByOrgId function, I'm not getting any error but at the same time, the db value is not updated.
I'm trying to update the amount value in the database but a certain value and it is not happening

Check this manual. It may answer your question https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-mongodb/reference/mongodb/repositories/modifying-methods.html
